# сортировка словарей

Tags: python

Привет, я печатаю с помощью цикла список словарей, на выходе получается это:

```
 {'symbol': 'STOL', 'Price': '0.08535400'}
{'symbol': 'LAVKA', 'Price': '0.02147000'}
```

Не знаю, правильно ли говорить, что это список, тк там нет квадратных скобок.. это JSON формат.
Мне нужно отсортировать по алфавиту значения ключей symbol и вывести на экран.
Код ниже не работает, выдает ошибку про  string indices must be integer.
По-моему, числа легко отсортировать, а как быть с алфавитом??

```
for j in slovari:
            if j in i['symbol']:
                a = i
                sor = sorted(a, key=lambda pair: pair['symbol'])
```

Comment: Позанудствую: это и не JSON тоже

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
dicts = [
    {'symbol': 'STOL', 'Price': '0.08535400'},
    {'symbol': 'A', 'Price': '0.02147000'},
    {'symbol': 'LAVKA', 'Price': '0.02147000'}]

print sorted([d['symbol'] for d in dicts])
# ['A', 'LAVKA', 'STOL']
```

Создается список со значениями symbol, а потом сортируется.

Способ с сортировкой по ключу (в вашем примере) удобно использовать для сортировки самих словарей в списке:

```
print sorted(dicts, key=lambda d: d['symbol'])

#[{'symbol': 'A', 'Price': '0.02147000'},
#{'symbol': 'LAVKA', 'Price': '0.02147000'},
#{'symbol': 'STOL', 'Price': '0.08535400'}]
```

Comment: думаю, надо бы уточнить что `print sorted([d['symbol'] for d in dicts])` это python2, а в python3 нужно `print(sorted([d['symbol'] for d in dicts]))`